# on click button function is not defined after adding if else to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

excuse me sir/ma'am
i'm making a form to submit data to the database using ajax and codeigniter
it works fine for inserting data but it has no validation whether the field is empty or not so im trying to add if else validation to the function. but after im adding the if else all my onclick button got the error saying 'x' is not defined

here is the code for the button

```php
<button type="button" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" onclick="on_save(0)">Submit</button>
<button type="button" id="batal_btn" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" onclick="on_back()">cancel</button>
```

here is the code for inserting data with ajax

```
<script>
function on_save(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '/bttdev3/tour/save',
            data: {
                    nama            : $("#nama").val(),
                    telpon          : $("#telpon").val(),
                    email           : $("#email").val(),
                    alamat          : $("#alamat").val(),
                    actions         : $actions
                },
        if (document.getElementById('nama').value == "") {
            alert ("Cek nama anda.");
            return false;
        } else
            success: function (reponse) {
                alert("Terima kasih telah mendaftar.");
                on_back();
            },
        });
    }

    function on_back(){
        var url = '/bttdev3/tour';
        window.open(url, "_self");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should do the validation *before* `$.ajax`. Right now your logic is sitting inside the middle of an object which is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: im new to ajax so forgive me if im wrong, so i need to declare new function for the if else validation?

Comment: It should look something more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ohLpbky0/

Comment: it works! thank you! how to credit you?
so i cant validate a data using if else function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your validation inside <kbd>button</kbd> click and if pass the validation call your AJAX function.

```
$("#submit_btn").on("click", function(event) {
  if (document.getElementById('nama').value == "") {
    alert("Cek nama anda.");
    event.preventDefault();
    //return false;
  } else {
    on_save();
  }
});
```

And your `on_save()` function:

```
function on_save() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: '/bttdev3/tour/save',
    data: {
      nama: $("#nama").val(),
      telpon: $("#telpon").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      alamat: $("#alamat").val(),
      actions: $actions
    },
    success: function(reponse) {
      alert("Terima kasih telah mendaftar.");
      on_back();
    }
  });
}

function on_back() {
  var url = '/bttdev3/tour';
  window.open(url, "_self");
}
```

Comment: i've tried this method, it displays the alert but it still saving the data and alerting me the success input
do i need to put to specific place?

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` . See updated answer. and no need `onclick="on_save(0)"` on your button.

Comment: thank you, it works! i modified it a bit adding else if function for other field